# Order by clause in UNION ALL sql query

Tags: sql-server-2005

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
ID,Bill_typeID,Cust_ID,Name,Reg_date,Account_Number,Amount,status
 FROM
(
 SELECT ID,Bill_typeID,Cust_ID,Name,Reg_date,Account_Number,Amount,status FROM Cust_Bill_Reg_M_Tbl 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ID,Bill_typeID,Cust_ID,Name,Reg_date,Account_Number,Amount,status FROM Rail_Ticket_Booking_M_Tbl 
)
order by CONVERT(datetime, Reg_date, 101) desc
```

I got this error.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
```

Whats wrong with my query? If it is wrong what is the actual method? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to alias the derived table (tmp):

```
SELECT  
ID,Bill_typeID,Cust_ID,Name,Reg_date,Account_Number,Amount,status 
 FROM 
( 
 SELECT ID,Bill_typeID,Cust_ID,Name,Reg_date,Account_Number,Amount,status FROM Cust_Bill_Reg_M_Tbl  
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT ID,Bill_typeID,Cust_ID,Name,Reg_date,Account_Number,Amount,status FROM Rail_Ticket_Booking_M_Tbl  
) tmp
order by CONVERT(datetime, Reg_date, 101) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your subquery, for example using `x`:

```
SELECT 
ID,Bill_typeID,Cust_ID,Name,Reg_date,Account_Number,Amount,status
 FROM
(
 SELECT ID,Bill_typeID,Cust_ID,Name,Reg_date,Account_Number,Amount,status FROM Cust_Bill_Reg_M_Tbl 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ID,Bill_typeID,Cust_ID,Name,Reg_date,Account_Number,Amount,status FROM Rail_Ticket_Booking_M_Tbl 
) x
order by CONVERT(datetime, Reg_date, 101) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an **alias** to subquery, like this:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  Bill_typeID,
  Cust_ID,
  Name,
  Reg_date,
  Account_Number,
  Amount,status
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    ID,
    Bill_typeID,
    Cust_ID,Name,
    Reg_date,
    Account_Number,
    Amount,
    status 
  FROM Cust_Bill_Reg_M_Tbl 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    ID,
    Bill_typeID,
    Cust_ID,
    Name,
    Reg_date,
    Account_Number,
    Amount,
    status 
  FROM Rail_Ticket_Booking_M_Tbl 
) Alias
order by CONVERT(datetime, Reg_date, 101) desc
```